# Looping through an array and assigning value to vector giving NULL incorrect value

Tags: r

I have a vector called "states" with all states 2 letters abbreviations, and a temp1 dataframe with 3 columns "Hospital.Name", "heart attack" and "State"

```
temp1   Hospital.Name                     heart attack State
99      PROVIDENCE ALASKA MEDICAL CENTER        13.4    AK
103     ALASKA REGIONAL HOSPITAL                14.5    AK
102     FAIRBANKS MEMORIAL HOSPITAL             15.5    AK
```

temp1 table has many more hospitals for every state

```
states
 [1] "AK" "AL" "AR" "AZ" "CA" "CO" "CT" "DC" "DE" "FL" "GA" "GU" "HI" "IA" "ID" "IL" "IN" "KS" "KY" "LA" "MA" "MD" "ME" "MI" "MN" "MO" "MS"
[28] "MT" "NC" "ND" "NE" "NH" "NJ" "NM" "NV" "NY" "OH" "OK" "OR" "PA" "PR" "RI" "SC" "SD" "TN" "TX" "UT" "VA" "VI" "VT" "WA" "WI" "WV" "WY
```

When I run this code by itself with the first value of the "states" array I get a correct result

```
resulttest <- subset(temp1[1,], State ==states[1])
resulttest

   Hospital.Name                     heart attack State
99 PROVIDENCE ALASKA MEDICAL CENTER         13.4    AK
```

But when I try to run this on a loop for all states in the "state" vector i get a NULL value

```
for (i in 1:length(states)){
     resulttest <- subset(temp1[1,], State ==states[i])
     }

# > resulttest
#
# [1] Hospital.Name heart attack  State        
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Can somebody help me with the loop function?, Thanks

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: btw - temp1[1,] means the first row of temp1

Comment: You can just do `df[df$State %in% states,]`

Comment: yes temp1[1,] means first row, I would like to just build a resulttest data frame with all the 1rst rows for the subset with that state I know that this will just have 1 item at the end of the loop since its not appending

Comment: If you want just the first row of each you can aggregate, i.e. `aggregate(.~state, df[df$State %in% states,], FUN=head, 1)`

Comment: This worked like charm, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing with the help from the comments, it also appends the results into a new dataframe called "result", num is a variable.  Thanks for the help :)

is a variable

```
 result <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 0))
 x <- c("Hospital.Name", "heart attack", "State")
 colnames(result) <- x

   for (i in 1:length(states)){
        resulttest <- temp1[temp1$State %in% states[i],]
        result[i,] <-resulttest1[num,]

      }
```